# Which child view will be called first under parent state in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to know sequence of call of below nested views if declared under parent view. Which nested view is called first?

.state('index',
{
    url: '/index',

```
views: {
 '': {
    templateUrl: 'AngularJS/Templates/indexView.html',
    controller: 'indexController'
 },
 'view1@index': {
     templateUrl: '/AngularJS/Templates/View1.html',
     controller: 'View1Controller'
 },
 'view2@index': {
     templateUrl: '/AngularJS/Templates/View2.html',
     controller: 'view2Controller'
 },
 'view3@index': {
     templateUrl: '/AngularJS/Templates/View3.html',
     controller: 'view3Controller'
 }
```

I want to know which will be called first, (view1 or view2 or view3). they have their respective controller.js file. I want to alter the sequence of call because it calls any random view. I have one logic which needs view3 to be called first and then view1 and view2

Please suggest.

Comment: What are you not using components ?

Comment: Yes. I am using only angularJs now. I am discovering the logic of sequence call in above mentioned nested views.

Comment: Is it hard  to answer this question or question itself is wrong?